# How to see stack/heap usage in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Is there a way to see the stack/heap usage in QtCreator? I'm getting a stack overflow error every now and then, and I'm trying to gather more information about it.

If not, is there a way in C++ (external tool or built in) to monitor the stack/heap?

EDIT: I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: "is there a way in C++ (external tool or built in) to monitor the stack/heap?" - Yes; *many*. Will write up an answer with details later if I have time. Quick tips; 1) most compilers let you define the size of the stack to use. 2) on linux, a poor mans tool is "top". 3) "perf" (on linux) can give *lots* of details. 4) [heaptrack](https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack) is useful. 5) On Windows look into [WPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer).   That's the tip of the iceberg - there's *much* more.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that in the mean time. I edited my post to specify my OS.

Comment: In general stackoverflows are fairly easy to solve with the debugger in Qt by looking at the stacktrace when they occur.